# Creating a new facebook application, no signed request is being sent through. Old app works

Tags: facebook

I have just created a new facebook application to use in a page tab. When I check for the signed_request it is empty.

So I checked another app that I have done in the past. It is on the same server and the only difference in the setup is the dir name.

http://example.com/app1/ works

and

http://example.com/app2/ doesn't

So I tried swapping the tab URLs in the apps over and app1 still works with app2s URL.

This lead me to believe there must be a problem with the way I have set up the application.

So I went through all the settings and made sure they were the same. They all are, except there are 2 that are not available on the app I just setup. They are "Encrypted Access Token" and "Requests 2.0 efficient" neither of which seem to relate to the problem.

I seem to remember in the past there was an option to pass through the signed request to canvas page, but I can no longer find it.

Has signed request been deprecated? I couldn't see any mention of that in the docs.

Any help/comment appreciated. Otherwise I am going to have to go back and re-use old apps with new content in them, and I only have about 15 more before I run out.

Cheers
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been resolved now, I can no longer replicate it with new applications.

Answer (score 3):

No, it wasn't deprecated.

There can be 2 issues that could cause this

1. You must have a trailing slash or a specific file on your page tab url.
   http://myapp.com/app/
   http://myapp.com/app/index.php
2. Your server for the second app is redirecting the request which causes it to lose the POST variables.

You should check if there aren't any redirects which usually occur form mod_rewrite. (.htaccess and such)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response, I have checked the URLs and the exact  same URL works in Apps I have created before today, but not in Apps I have created today. This seems to rule out both of those possibilities right? And they are both on the same server, under the same virtual host, and are sibling sub dirs.

Comment: I can confirm opening a new application just last week and having a page tab application work just fine.

Try using .htaccess to disable rewrites for that directory, that's what worked for me.
Maybe there's a rule that doesn't pertain to the new application.

Comment: I have had 3 apps all work fine in the last week - last one on Friday, it has only been today that I have had the problem. There is no .htaccess in the individual dirs, and both dirs work on a Facebook tab that I setup weeks ago, just not on the new one. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: Canvas apps can't end with a file, they must end with a directory.